# Heroku/sendgrid can't install this addon

Tags: django, heroku, sendgrid

I've created an django project on heroku which can send emails using sendgrid, this app worked as a charm. I created this app to study a bit about how sendgrid, django and heroku works together.
Using the same heroku account, I've created another project after this first project,
which would be definitive, and in this project I change the sender email many times, but it is my emails with a custom domain. Unfortunately I had my heroku/sendgrid (I don't have a sendgrid account, I only needed heroku to install sendgrid:starter addon in my project) account banned. When I try to install sendgrid addon in a project which I've deployed, this message is returned(in this case, I am using a custom domain to my email: victor.s.silva@unesp.br):

```
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.42.4 to 7.42.6.
Creating sendgrid:starter on ⬢ myproject... !
 ▸    An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create
 ▸    sendgrid:starter. Please try again later.
```

#sometimes this message inform that I have my sendgrid account banned.

When I try to install this addon in a deployed project in another account(@gmail.com), I get this message:

```
 ▸    The account "victor.santos.cd@gmail.com" is not permitted to install the
 ▸    sendgrid add-on at this time. Your account may require additional
 ▸    verification. Please visit
 ▸    https://tools.heroku.support/addons-verification to complete this process.
```

The page crashs when I send my cell number.

I have no idea what I have to do to solve this. As I have a free heroku account, I can't create a ticket, once I haven't sendgrid addon installed in my project. So, I need some help to reactive my sendgrid permission.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Trying to add Sendgrid via console command I get the same message response. I logged a support ticket at Sendgrid but no reply yet. Have you found the solution? or reason why this is happening? I used your link to verify my account by phone but still does not work